# Why do I keep getting a match_failure?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, match

I'm currently writing an interpreter for c flat in ocaml. I was given a makefile for source code containing an abstract syntax tree file, a main file etc. I am trying to implement arithmetic but I keep getting this error(match_failure) when I run test case. The test case is in a .cf file. This is the content of the file 
"print_int((9+6+(11/11)+1+(-6))*(-1));"
Can someone please help me understand why is error is occurring?

This is my code :

```
open Ast;;
open Env;;
open Store;;

let allocateMem env = env;; (* TODO: implement this function *)


let rec eval_expr (expr:expr) (ps:proc_state) (env:environment) (store:store) : int = match expr with
      Add (e1, e2) -> 
      let r1 = eval_expr e1 ps env store in
      let r2 = eval_expr e2 ps env store in
      r1 + r2
  |  Sub (e1, e2) ->
      let r1 = eval_expr e1 ps env store in
      let r2 = eval_expr e2 ps env store in
      r1 - r2
  |  Mul (e1, e2) ->
      let r1 = eval_expr e1 ps env store in
      let r2 = eval_expr e2 ps env store in
      r1 * r2
  |  Div (e1, e2) ->
      let r1 = eval_expr e1 ps env store in
      let r2 = eval_expr e2 ps env store in
      r1 / r2
  |  Neg (e1) ->
      let r1 = eval_expr e1 ps env store in
      r1 * -1
  | IntConst i -> i
  | Id (e1) ->
      let l = binding_of env e1 in
      let Intval(i)= value_at(store,l) in
      i;;

;;

(* eval_expr: expr -> proc_state -> env -> store -> value *)
let rec eval_cond cond ps env store = match cond with
  Equal (e1, e2) ->
    let r1 = eval_expr e1 ps env store in
    let r2 = eval_expr e2 ps env store in
    r1 == r2
(* TODO: add more *)
;;

type stmtEvalRes = Next | BreakOut | ContinueOn;;

(* eval_stmt: stmt -> proc_state -> env -> store -> stmtEvalRes*proc_state *)
let rec eval_stmt stmt ps env store = match stmt with
| PrintInt e ->
    let r = eval_expr e ps env store in
    print_int r; (Next, ps, store)
| PrintStr s ->
    print_string (Str.global_replace (Str.regexp "\\\\n") "\n" s); 
    (* Escaping characters here because it's not done in the parser *)
    (Next, ps, store)
| List (stmt1::stmts) -> eval_stmt stmt1 ps env store
  (* TODO: complete this case so that all statements in the list evaluated *)
;;
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the error. Please also post any compiler warnings you get when compiling the code.

Comment: I updated it. Also, I didn't get any warnings.

Comment: I don't see how that can be true if you're getting a match failure - unless you explicitly disabled exhaustiveness warnings. Note that you won't get any warnings if you run make without changing the code or running `make clean` because it won't compile any files that haven't changed.

Comment: Anyway, when I said "reproduce the error", I meant "compile your code, run it and get the same error you do". When I try to run your code, I get a bunch of compilation errors about the types and constructors not being defined. So clearly this is not enough code to reproduce the error. It would be great if you could reduce your problem to a single file that contains all the relevant definitions, can be compiled and run and produces the same error message when run (while hopefully keeping the file short by cutting out anything that's not relevant to the error without breaking the program).

Comment: I did make clean and then make all and I got this warning : "Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
(Sub (_, _)|Mul (_, _)|Div (_, _)|Neg _|Id _|At (_, _)|Deref _|AddressOf _|
Call (_, _)|Pre _|Post _)
"

Comment: On which match did you get that warning? In your `eval_expr` function you do match on some of those, so the warning must come from somewhere else? (That said the match in `eval_expr` is clearly not exhaustive either if all of those cases exist, so you should be getting another warning about that as well - unless the file you're editing isn't among the files you're compiling at all)

Comment: I'm not sure which match but line 12 is where the warning occurred. And this what comes after that line : let rec eval_expr (expr:expr) (ps:proc_state) (env:environment) (store:store) : int = match expr with

Comment: Okay, so are you that the code you're looking at (or, more relevantly, the code that you posted here) is the code that you're compiling? Because you clearly are matching `Sub`, `Mul`, `Div`, `Neg` and `Id` in the code that you posted, but the warning says you're not.

Comment: I just saved it notepad++. Then I did a make clean followed by a make all and got the same warning..

Comment: Beware that `==` is not the usual equality testing in OCaml — it works here because you deal with integers but would lead to surprises if you, say, used `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

According to the warning, we can reconstruct that the `expr` type, has the following set of constructors: `Add, Sub, Mul,Div, Neg, Id, At, Deref, AddressOf, Call, Pre, Post`, i.e., 11 branches, you have only 7.

I suspect, that the original code, that you've got as an assignment, had the following implementation:

```
let rec eval_expr (expr:expr) (ps:proc_state) (env:environment) (store:store) : int = match expr with
      Add (e1, e2) -> 
      let r1 = eval_expr e1 ps env store in
      let r2 = eval_expr e2 ps env store in
      r1 + r2
 (* TODO: add more *)
```

That's why, when you're compiling the original code, you got the warning:

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. 
Here is an example of a value that is not matched: 
(Sub (, _)|Mul (, )|Div (, )|Neg _|Id _|At (, )|Deref _|AddressOf _| Call (, _)|Pre _|Post _) "
```

The code that you're showing to us, is not the code, that you're trying to compile. Maybe you're playing with it in a toplevel.

As sepp2k mentioned, the testing expression doesn't contain call expression, that means, that with high probability you're compiling and running the original code, i.e., that one that contains only one `Add` branch, not the code, that you've written. That's why you're getting match failure. (But sooner or later, you still need to get all 11 branches written).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no call in the given expression. `print_int` almost certainly gets parsed as the statement `PrintInt` (see `eval_stmnt`).